# How can I present only specific list as my output after using a condition on many other lists

Tags: r, list, loops

Suppose I have huge number of lists each contains 3 rows ( I present here 3 of them) and I would like to get the name (List1,List2,etc..) of the list that have the minimum values per first and third rows out of the given 3 rows.In this case List3 is the answar (0.1948026 and 0.1125526 have the minimum values of all lists),How can I present only List3 as my output?

```
    list1<-list(
     0.3318594
    ,0.1296125
    , 0.1262203)

   list2<- list(
     0.3654229
     ,0.1428565
     ,0.1552035)

   list3<- list(
     0.1948026
     ,0.1272514
     ,0.1125526)
```

Comment: What if one list has a minimum value in the first row while another has in the third? What would be the desired output?

Comment: Hello @ David Arenburg, The desired output should be two lists' names and the related values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lists are defined in your global envrionment and not in a list .. which is a bad habit. Despite this, you can solve your problem this way:

```
# first catch your lists names in your envrionment
lnames = Filter(function(x) class(get(x))=='list', ls(pattern="list\\d+", env=globalenv()))

# gather values in the matrix - the colummn names will be the list names
m = sapply(lnames, get)

# to get the name of the list(s) with min value in 1st and 3rd position
colnames(m)[unique(apply(m[c(1,3),],1,which.min))]
#[1] "list3"
```

Comment: Thanks @Colonel Beauvel, It works...If I may ask how can I evoid defining lists in the global envrionment ?

Comment: by gathering your lists in a list, like `bigList = list(list1, list2, list3, ...)`. If you defined your lists by an iterating process, you can use `bigList = lapply(myIterator, function(iteratee) #return a list after operations)`

Answer (score 4):

`data.table` is probably going to be the fastest solution for this if you have lots of lists.

You could do:

```
library(data.table)
#add all in a list
the_lists <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

Or it would probably be much better (if your lists are all in the global environment) to do the following as per @DavidArenburg 's comment:

```
#this will create a list with all lists in your global env 
#that are named list1, list2, list3 etc.
the_lists <- mget(ls(pattern = "list.+"))

#create a data table ouf of them 
#notice that every row represents a list here
all_lists <- rbindlist(the_lists)
#find the list with the minimum row
#which for this case means find the min location of each column 
mins <- as.numeric(all_lists[, lapply(.SD, which.min)])

#> mins
#[1] 3 3 3
```

And then just use mins to retrieve the list you want.

For row 1 use:

```
> the_lists[mins[1]]
$list3
$list3[[1]]
[1] 0.1948026

$list3[[2]]
[1] 0.1272514

$list3[[3]]
[1] 0.1125526
```

and for row 3:

```
> the_lists[mins[3]]
$list3
$list3[[1]]
[1] 0.1948026

$list3[[2]]
[1] 0.1272514

$list3[[3]]
[1] 0.1125526
```

Using `mget` as suggested by @DavidArenburg the list names are created, and will be shown as above.

To get the value and the names:

```
 > data.frame(min_loc = mins[c(1,3)], names = names(the_lists)[c(mins[c(1,3)])])
  min_loc names
1       3 list3
2       3 list3
```

Comment: I would suggest getting the lists using something like `mget(ls(pattern = "list.+"))` because OP stated he has huge amount of lists.

Comment: You still missing the lists names though. Maybe something like `unlist(the_lists[mins[1]])[1] ; unlist(the_lists[mins[3]])[3]` but it's not very clean.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Looks like the names are preserved with your `mget` suggestion.

Comment: Yes I know, but the OP wants just the name + value, not the whole list, see my comment above.

Comment: Yeah now I got it @DavidArenburg .

Comment: Hello @LyzandeR, I got this error after running  mins <- as.numeric(all_lists[, lapply(.SD, which.min)]) 
Error in setnames(jval, jvnames) : x has no column names .What could be the problem?

Comment: @mql4beginner Have you checked that `mget` chooses the lists that you want? `pattern = "list.+"` above will choose lists with the names list1, list2, list3 etc. If your list names are different you would need to change the pattern.

Comment: Here is the output that I get by using mget:the_lists
$all_lists
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

$list1
$list1[[1]]
[1] 0.3318594

$list1[[2]]
[1] 0.1296125

$list1[[3]]
[1] 0.1262203


$list2
$list2[[1]]
[1] 0.3654229

$list2[[2]]
[1] 0.1428565

$list2[[3]]
[1] 0.1552035


$list3
$list3[[1]]
[1] 0.1948026

$list3[[2]]
[1] 0.1272514

$list3[[3]]
[1] 0.1125526


$the_lists
$the_lists$the_lists
named list()

Comment: You already have some new objects there, you will need to make you regex more specific. something like `mget(ls(pattern = "^list\\d.*"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Collect lists
collection.list <- list("list1"=list1,"list2"=list2,"list3"=list3)

#Build data
matrix <- do.call(rbind,collection.list)

# Select columns
used.columns <- c(1,3)

# Find minimum value
min.ind <- which(matrix[,used.columns]==min(unlist(matrix[,used.columns])),arr.ind = TRUE)

# Find name
names(collection.list)[min.ind[,"row"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work,

```
common_list <- mapply(c, list1, list2, list3, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
a <- lapply(mapply(c, list1, list2, list3, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), min)
b <- paste("list", unlist(lapply(mapply(c, list1, list2, list3, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), which.min)))
data.frame(Min_value = unlist(a), List = unlist(b))


# Min_value   List
# 1 0.1948026 list 3
# 2 0.1272514 list 3
# 3 0.1125526 list 3
```

However, this gives minimum for every row.